# How to format Y-axis displayed numbers in pyqtgraph?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqtgraph

I see numbers on Y-axis like this:

```
1.935
1.9325
1.93
1.9275
1.925
```

But I need to see this:

```
1.9350
1.9325
1.9300
1.9275
1.9250
```

How can I set the AxisItem to show always fixed number of digits after decimal point?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to subclass the AxisItem and use tickStrings to format the values:

```
class FmtAxisItem(pg.AxisItem):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def tickStrings(self, values, scale, spacing):
        return [f'{v:.4f}' for v in values]
```

Then tell the plotter to use the axis:

```
self.chartWidget = pg.PlotWidget(axisItems={'left': FmtAxisItem(orientation='left')})
```

Comment: Is this still the way to go? Does work, just wondering if there is a better way/simpler. Tx